# Formula for division of each individual term in a summation

Tags: c, math, complexity-theory

Example:
[image: ![math]http://mathurl.com/83cpbet.png]

When the division is applied as a whole, the result is,

[image: http://mathurl.com/79p3hoh]

The summation formula is given by,
[image: summation]

The above can be easily calculated in O(1), using the rules of summation.

But when it is applied to each term individually(truncating after the decimal point in the quotient),
=0+1+1+2+3+3+4+5=19. [using normal `int`/`int` division in C]

The above method requires O(N) as rules of summation can NOT be applied.

<s>I understand the above is due to loss of precision is more when the division is applied to each term rather than at the last.</s> But this is exacly what I need.[In the above example, 19 is the required solution and not 21]

Is there a formula that would serve as a shortcut for applying division individually to each term, similar to summation?

Comment: Is the summation always of the form `Σ(i=1..n; (2i-1)/3)`? If not, then you'll realize the answer is "no". Also, it's not due to a loss of precision (such as you get with floating point arithmetic); it's how integer division is defined.

Comment: @outis:yes, it is always of that form.

Comment: Just to be clear, you actually want to "lose accuracy", and want to compute (int)1/3 + (int)3/3 + (int)5/3 ..., correct? Purely out of curiosity, I am intrigued to know in what context that problem arises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you get:

0 + (1+1+2) + (3+3+4) + 5

Let's multiply this by 3:

0 + (3+3+6) + (9+9+12) + 15

And compare it with the numerator of (1+...+15)/3:

1 + (3+5+7) + (9+11+13) + 15

You can clearly see that the sum you're seeking is losing 3 every 3 terms to the numerator or 1 in every term on average. And it doesn't matter how we group terms into triples:

(0+3+3) + (6+9+9) + 12+15
(1+3+5) + (7+9+11) + 13+15

or even

0+3 + (3+6+9) + (9+12+15)
1+3 + (5+7+9) + (11+13+15)

So your sum*3 is less than the numerator of (1+...+15)/3 by about the number of terms.

And the numerator can be calculated using the formula for the sum of the arithmetic progression: `n`<sup>2</sup>, where `n` is the number of terms in the sum:

1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15 = 2<sup>8</sup> = 64

Now you subtract 8 from 64, get 56 and divide it by 3, getting 18.6(6). The number isn't equal to 19 because `n` (the number of terms) wasn't a multiple of 3.

So, the final formula isn't exactly (`n`<sup>2</sup>-`n`)/3, but differs in value at most by 1 from the correct one.

In fact, it's:

(n*n-n+1)/3 rounded down or calculated using integer division.

Plugging the number(s) into it we get:

(8*8-8+1)/3 = 57/3 = 19

Comment: Apologies if my question is not clear, I am using the integer(int/int) division of C for each individual term as I don't care about the precision.

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you need and why. However, in base-3 fixed or floating point arithmetic you can divide each odd number from 1 to 15 by 3 without losing anything to rounding and then you can add the fractions and get 21+1/3 as the result.

Comment: I've restructured the question now. Please let me know if you are still not able to understand anything.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes there is such a formula.

Long answer (as I guess you want the formula):

How to get it: You already realized that the difference between the summation formula and the sum of the int devision came from the rounding of the int division at each summand.

Make a table with the rows:

First row, the result of each summand, when you divide with full precision.

Second row, the reuslt of each summand, when you perform integer division.

And third row, the difference of both.

Now you should realize the pattern, its always 1/3, 0, 2/3.

That came from the division by 3, you could proof that formal if you want (e.g. induction).

So in the end your formula is: (n^2)/3 - (n/3)

the n*n/3 is the regular summation formula, and as for all full 3 summands 1 is lost we subtract n/3.

Answer (score 1):

The result is going to be

```
1+1 + 2 + 3+3 + 4 + 5+5 + 6 + 7+7 + 8 + 9+9 + 10 + ...
```

in other words all odd numbers appear twice and all even numbers once. The sum of first `n` natural numbers is `n*(n+1)/2` so the sum of first `n` even natural numbers is twice that and the sum of first `n` odd numbers is instead `n*n`.

I think you now have all pieces to get the result you need...

Answer (score 1):

The sums you need are, for increasing `n`s:
1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 14, 19, 24, 30, 36 ...

Plug these into the [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences™ (OEIS™)](http://oeis.org) and you get [A007980](http://oeis.org/A007980) as the series that fits your requirements. It is calculated as a(n)=ceil((n+1)*(n+2)/3).

This makes a(0) = 1, a(1) = 2, a(6) = 19, meaning the index is offset by 2: sum(1,8) = a(8-2).

Answer (score 0):

```
Σ((2i+1)/3) where i =0 to n-1 and Σ((2i+1)/3) = n*n/3
```

Comment: Hi Prasad, You've used the rules of summation to arrive at this result, but this cannot be applied to my requirement as each term needs to be divided individually and 1/3 cannot be done at the last step.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct fraction {
    int n;//numerator
    int d;//denominator
} Fraction;

int gcd(int x, int y){
    x = (x < 0)? -x : x;
    y = (y < 0)? -y : y;
    while(y){
        int wk;
        wk = x % y;
        x = y;
        y = wk;
    }

    return x;
}

Fraction rcd(Fraction x){
    int gcm;
    gcm = gcd(x.n, x.d);
    x.n /= gcm;
    x.d /= gcm;
    return x;
}

Fraction add(Fraction x, Fraction y){
    x.n = y.d*x.n + x.d*y.n;
    x.d = x.d*y.d;
    return rcd(x);
}

int main(void){
    Fraction sum = {0,1};
    int n;

    for(n=1;n<=8;++n){
        Fraction x = { 2*n-1, 3 };
        sum = add(sum, x);
    }
    printf("%d/%d=",sum.n,sum.d);
    printf("%d",sum.n/sum.d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's worse than pretending to be using base-3 fixed-point for the terms. :) The OP asked for an O(1) formula.

Comment: @Alex , Σ((2i-1)/3) -> 1/3Σ(2i-1) -> 1/3{2Σi -n} -> 1/3{2n(n+1)/2 -n} -> 1/3 {n^2} : O(1)

Comment: The OP wanted a formula for the sum of terms divided by 3 like in C, that is, as if it wasn't a normal division, but rather integer/rounded down/truncated, you know.